# No se despliega la imagen en el siguiente código python con kivy

Tags: python, imagen

```
class MainWid(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(MainWid, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        miConeccion=sqlite3.connect("vel.db")
        miCursor=miConeccion.cursor()
        try:
            instruccion = "SELECT sec_nombre, sec_desc, sec_cant, sec_precio, sec_foto FROM secundaria"
            miCursor.execute(instruccion)
            filas=miCursor.fetchall()
            if len(filas)!=0:
                for fila in filas:
                    nombre = fila[0]
                    desc = fila[1]
                    imagen = Image()
                    imagen.source = fila[4]
                    eti = Label()
                    eti.image=imagen
                    self.ids.container_y.add_widget(Button(text=nombre))
                    self.ids.container_y.add_widget(eti)
```

Comment: Podrias poner el resultado de ```fila[4]``` tal vez la URL de la imagen esta mal

Comment: Ya lo hice, usando "imagen = image(fila[4]) / self.ids.container(Image=imagen)" y funciona perfectamente, o sea que el dato de imagen está correcto

Comment: El *dato* es toda la ruta de la imagen o solo el nombre de la imagen?

Comment: el  dato "fila[4"] es la ruta del archivo ".png" que quiero desplegar, que está grabado en un campo de base de datos. Lo convierto a imagen y después lo despliego, o lo pretendo desplegar, según use "Image" o "Label"

Answer (score 0):

El asunto de desplegar una imagen en un botón se resuelve usando la instrucción
"background_normal".

Aquí un ejemplo sencillo

imagen="imagen.png"
add_widget(Button(background_normal=imagen))